# Image inside a div to be a different height than the rest

Tags: css, image, html

I'm struggling to set an img's height inside a div to be taler than the other img's on the rest of my site, can anyone advise, thanks

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="project">

    <img src="../../../Images/Nu Space/Nu Space LH.jpg" alt="Nu Space LH" class="image" height="auto" width="580">

    <img src="../../../Images/Nu Space/Nu Space BC.jpg" alt="Nu Space BC" class="image" height="auto" width="580">

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
img {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: auto;
}

img li {
    margin-top: 75px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.project {
    width: 700px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    left: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Struggling how? What happens instead of what you expect? Try recreating the problem in http://jsfiddle.net and post it here for faster help.

Comment: Not sure if thi will show it but the issue is that the top img is a letterhead and the bottom one is a business card so the top one needs to have more depth without changing any other divs http://jsfiddle.net/tT8JH/

Answer (score 0):

```
div > img {
    width: (desired width in %);
    height: (desired height in %):
}
```

Edit: Sorry I was not exact in my explanations, but this will change only the images inside a div, which was what the author wanted. I believe he has other images on the webpage, which should have different size.

Comment: The concern is the height, not the width, and surely this will change it for all img's throughout the site

Comment: Please, check the guide [answer]. I'm reviewing your post in the *Low Quality Review*, I'm positive you don't want to be associated with that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
.project 
{
    width: 700px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    left: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.project .image1 
{
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tT8JH/2/